# Serve Javascript file without timestamp and separate from application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I would like to serve a specific js file in production (heroku) without timestamp.
I am able to serve the file separately, but it is served with timestamp which I don't want. The reason is I want this file get accessed by other sites.

Here are the codes:

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'ca4me', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, :cache => false %>
```

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require bootstrap.min
```

application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( ca4me.js )
```

HTML source in production environment:

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-b83af88604eb0fb1867384db77b826ae.js"></script>
<script cache="false" data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/ca4me-fcff49d8b1799052a3f84c913160f6b2.js"></script>
```

So is there away I can serve ca4me.js without the timestamp?

Comment: put it in `/public/`, not inside the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File**

> The reason is I want this file get accessed by other sites.

We did this:

```
/public/your_js_file.js
```

This is a pain to keep updated, but means your app will always have the file available at `/____.js`. Indeed, when you use asset precompilation, the assets are deployed to folders in the `public` directory like this:

```
- public
 |-stylesheets
 |-javascripts
 |-images
```

If you're looking to keep a file available for other sites (like a widget or something), I would personally keep the code base separate from your Rails app, using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or similar (saving the file to `rails_app/public` directly.

---

**Digest**

I wanted to learn about this, and  I [found this](https://github.com/spohlenz/digestion/issues/3):

```
config.assets.digest_exclusions << /fontawesome/
```

The only problem is this is for the [digestion gem](https://github.com/spohlenz/digestion/blob/master/test/test_asset_paths.rb) - **meaning it won't be available in Rails 4**. I am still trying to find information regarding how to accomplish this in Rails 4, and I would recommend looking at my solution above for now

--

Personally, I would rely on the asset pipeline for my assets, and keep a file in `public` if I wanted a static location for people to access. The likelihood is that file (library?) will be updated in conjunction, albeit exclusively, with the Rails app; meaning you may wish to keep the code bases separate